# Why am I reading non-standard voltages on my house wiring?

Tags: electrical

I have a quick query regarding household wiring .When I connected the Green wire with red wire , the Fluke multimeter read 177 V ac, green and black wire read 44 V ac . The electric supply that comes in is 220V ac. Can someone please help me understand what does 177 and 44 V ac mean here ?

Comment: If you don't tell us what country you are in, we have no idea what the green/black/red colour code means. Also this seems like a question about engineering (or household maintenance) not physics.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: My bad, @Qmechanic , I will post it to the other forum , thanks .

Comment: Sounds like you have a neutral (black in pre-1970 UK wiring) to Earth (Green) fault, somewhere between your house and the substation (transformer). Get that sorted by your electricity supplier. Live (red) to neutral, at 221V, is OK.

Comment: @Qmechanic  This is DIY.SE material, if they deem that the question is clear enough.

Comment: @BrianDrummond ideally, what shall my multimeter read when probes are put between Green and negative wiring (maybe 0 V ?) . Basically, i am working as a petroleum engineer on an oil rig . The rig supplies gives us 440 V , we have a transformer for converting it to 220 V ac and 110 V ac . I just found out this and found it a bit interesting & peculiar ...I always thought that the negative terminal and grounding terminal shall read 0 Volts , and if the grounding cable is not shorted with any other load , we CAN USE GROUDING cable as th enegative cable ?

Comment: If the 440VAC is 3phase, then the values read on a DMM will not match what is expected from a single phase system.

Comment: First, that's Neutral not Negative, on an AC circuit. Secondly, I wouldn't be worried by a couple of volts or even 5V, but 44V indicates a problem that must be fixed because it's part of the safety system. Third : Using Ground instead of Neutral in a modern installation would trip the RCD. Neutral is for return current; Ground is for safety. There ARE wiring systems that combine them; but the conductor size must then be several times the Live conductor.

Comment: Noting that 177+44 is 221 so H-N is normal line voltage... it sounds like a problem with neutral-ground bonding.  The concern is not that neutral is 44V from ground, it's that neutral is out of control.

Comment: Thanks @BrianDrummond

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a floating neutral. The primary and secondary of most transformers are isolated, and unless there is some specific reason that it needs to be isolated the installer needs to make this connection. I would consult the wiring diagram, it typically would show that the secondary wiring should be connected to ground and where it should be connected.

Comment: Neutral MIGHT be fine : a floating GND could yield the same measurements. There's no way to tell from just these measurements. But either way, it needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are supporting 110V-220V, you are probably working out of El NEC or CEC.  That calls this a **separately derived system**.

Such a system requires a neutral-ground equipotential bond at the first disconnect past the transformer.  This connects the neutral bus in the panel to the ground bus in the panel.

If you use North American style service equipment, they usually make this easy.  However you can also use a heavy wire. In fact I recommend you do.  It is useful to clamp a meter around the bond; any current there is fault current.

Further, the ground bus must be tied to “earth” or whatever passes for that on an oil rig, I.e. the metal structure.

Note there may not be any obvious ground bar or wires, if wires are carried in metal boxes and metal conduits, as is typical in industrial installations.  In that case, the neutral-ground equipotential bond can connect to the metal panel chassis itself, via an approved lug.  This paragraph exactly describes what I have in three different buildings.